# Positioning wizard at the centre of the screen win32 application using propertysheet

Tags: c++, win32gui, propertysheet

Created two pages wizard in win32 application using Propertysheetpage. The wizard is not positioned at the center of the screen. To position the pages at the center I have written the below code for the first page(assuming 2nd page will get reflected with the position of 1st page) but it is not working. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
static LRESULT WINAPI sWelcomePageDlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

  {

   HWND hwndOwner = NULL;
   RECT rcOwner,rcDlg,rc;

   switch (uMsg) 
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
             hwndOwner = GetDesktopWindow();
             GetWindowRect(hwndOwner, &rcOwner);
             GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rcDlg);
             rc.left = (rcOwner.right - rcOwner.left)/2 - (rcDlg.right - rcDlg.left)/2;
             rc.right = rc.left + (rcDlg.right - rcDlg.left);
             rc.top = (rcOwner.bottom - rcOwner.top)/2 - (rcDlg.bottom - rcDlg.top)/2;
             rc.bottom = rc.top + (rcDlg.bottom - rcDlg.top);
             SetWindowPos (hwnd, NULL, rc.left, rc.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOSIZE);
             SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_WELCOMETEXTSTATIC), Info);
             break;

       case WM_COMMAND:
            break;

       case WM_NOTIFY:
            LPNMHDR lpnm = (LPNMHDR)lParam;

            switch (lpnm->code)
            {
              case PSN_SETACTIVE:
                PropSheet_SetWizButtons(GetParent(hwnd), PSWIZB_NEXT | PSWIZB_CANCEL);
                break;
              case PSN_WIZNEXT:
                SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, DWLP_MSGRESULT, IDD_FINISHPAGE);
                break;
            }

      break;
   }

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hwnd passed into your window proc is a handle to a wizard *page*. For a handle to the wizard itself, call GetParent( hwnd ).

Btw., screen dimensions are also available via GetSystemMetrics(), SM_CXSCREEN / SM_CYSCREEN.